# apache doesn't return response header when serving css js

Tags: django, apache, character-encoding, response, uwsgi

When i vi the css on the server it looks perfectly normal
However once the css arrives in the browser its like this:

```
oÛ6þn ÿáfoH»Å–eA!Ë¶$mlIP8Š
```

Also it has no response header

does anybody know what can cause this?

i have a vanilla apache setup with only alias matches and :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
FileETag none
```

Comment: I've tried switching off mod-deflate, but now all static files 404 grrrrr :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the same problem when my server was configured with conflicting <Location X>SetHandler</Location> statements

Comment: I think this might be it. Can't check anymore i'm afraid since I fixed the problem by switching to cherokee ;) I will check with a server backup later on